# How to implement the following C code in Python? (typedef, enums and switch)

Tags: python, c, enums, switch-statement, typedef

I have the following part of code in C:

```
typedef enum {
    CAN_NORMAL_MODE = 0x00,
    CAN_SLEEP_MODE = 0x01,
    CAN_INTERNAL_LOOPBACK_MODE = 0x02,
    CAN_LISTEN_ONLY_MODE = 0x03,
    CAN_CONFIGURATION_MODE = 0x04,
    CAN_EXTERNAL_LOOPBACK_MODE = 0x05,
    CAN_CLASSIC_MODE = 0x06,
    CAN_RESTRICTED_MODE = 0x07,
    CAN_INVALID_MODE = 0xFF
} CAN_OPERATION_MODE;

//more code here in the middle...

d = something 
switch (d) {
    case CAN_NORMAL_MODE:
        mode = CAN_NORMAL_MODE;
        break;
    case CAN_SLEEP_MODE:
        mode = CAN_SLEEP_MODE;
        break;
   // more cases here, not shown for readability
    default:
        mode = CAN_INVALID_MODE;
        break;
}
```

Here *d* is a byte that I read from other sources. The switch statement is inside another function, and more code is there, but I don't think it is necessary to show as it does nothing to do with this part.

My problem is: I'm trying to *translate* this code to Python, for reasons, so that it is *sintactically similar* to the original C code (that is, I don't want the Python code to be radically different, so another person that has worked with the original C code can understand and use easily the Python code). I'm not sure how to implement the functionality in this code snippet in Python language without doing an endless stream of *if-elif...else* statements. I think there should an easier (pythonic) way to do it, but I'm not sure how to implement the *typedef*, *enum* and *switch* statements in Python. I have read some ways to implement the *enum* clause creating a class with the aliases and values as attributes, like this:

```
class myClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.CAN_NORMAL_MODE = 0x00
        self.CAN_SLEEP_MODE = 0x01
        self.CAN_INTERNAL_LOOPBACK_MODE = 0x02
    #etc
```

I have also come across a clever way of implementing a switch statement in Python, with a function like this (without any relation to my actual problem, just to show the structure of the implementation):

```
def switch(argument):
    switcher = {
        1: "January",
        2: "February",
        3: "March",
        4: "April",
        5: "May",
        6: "June",
        7: "July",
        8: "August",
        9: "September",
        10: "October",
        11: "November",
        12: "December"
    }
    print switcher.get(argument, "Invalid month")
```

But I can't come across a way of combining this two things in an easy and understandable way. 
Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: `but I'm not sure how to implement the typedef, enum and switch statements in Python.` You don't

Comment: The C code looks like it can be replaced with `mode = (0x00 <= d && d <= 0x07) ? d : 0xFF`, which in Python would be `mode = d if 0x00 <= d <= 0x07 else 0xFF`.

For the enum, use [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum)

Comment: Related: [Does Python have an equivalent to switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429505/does-python-have-an-equivalent-to-switch)

Comment: If you have the C files, you can try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66037988/208880) to generate the Python `Enum`s from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the enum itself, you seem to be making it harder than it needs to be.  An enum can be mapped very cleanly to a python module containing only a bunch of variable definitions, such as this:

**can_operation_mode.py**:

```
CAN_NORMAL_MODE = 0x00
CAN_SLEEP_MODE = 0x01
CAN_INTERNAL_LOOPBACK_MODE = 0x02
CAN_LISTEN_ONLY_MODE = 0x03
CAN_CONFIGURATION_MODE = 0x04
CAN_EXTERNAL_LOOPBACK_MODE = 0x05
CAN_CLASSIC_MODE = 0x06
CAN_RESTRICTED_MODE = 0x07
CAN_INVALID_MODE = 0xFF
```

That provides useful namespacing (which C enums don't), but also the ability to import those names into another module so as to use them C style, without module name.  Of course, the tradeoff is that they are modifiable.

As for the `switch`, no, Python does not have a direct analog to C's `switch`, at least not if you disqualify the sort of `if` / `else if` / `else` construct you describe in the question:

**other_module.py**:

```
import can_operation_mode.*

d = something 
if   d == CAN_NORMAL_MODE:
    mode = CAN_NORMAL_MODE
elif d == CAN_SLEEP_MODE:
    mode = CAN_SLEEP_MODE
// more cases here ...
else:
    mode = CAN_INVALID_MODE
```

Frankly, though, I don't see what's wrong with that from a perspective of maintaining syntactic similarity to the original C.  It looks pretty similar to me, right down to the use of colons.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem in this way. I didn't want to do this kind of if-elif... construction, and I admit that I was a little obsessed with recreating the exact functionality of the C code in Python (instead of similar code that may work in a different way, but obtains the same results). Nevertheless, the most straightforward path (yours) was succesful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
from enum import IntEnum

class CAN_OPERATION_MODE(IntEnum):
    NORMAL_MODE = 0x00
    SLEEP_MODE = 0x01
    INTERNAL_LOOPBACK_MODE = 0x02
    LISTEN_ONLY_MODE = 0x03
    CONFIGURATION_MODE = 0x04
    EXTERNAL_LOOPBACK_MODE = 0x05
    CLASSIC_MODE = 0x06
    RESTRICTED_MODE = 0x07
    INVALID_MODE = 0xFF

    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        return cls.INVALID_MODE

d = something
mode = CAN_OPERATION_MODE(d)
```

I would also  remove the `_MODE` from all the enum names.

Answer (score 0):

How about a dictionary? You could assign each value to the corresponding mode, then call it:

```
modes = {
    0x00 : 'CAN_NORMAL_MODE',
    0x01 : 'CAN_SLEEP_MODE',
    0x02 : 'CAN_INTERNAL_LOOPBACK_MODE',
    0x03 : 'CAN_LISTEN_ONLY_MODE',
    0x04 : 'CAN_CONFIGURATION_MODE',
    0x05 : 'CAN_EXTERNAL_LOOPBACK_MODE',
    0x06 : 'CAN_CLASSIC_MODE',
    0x07 : 'CAN_RESTRICTED_MODE',
    0xFF : 'CAN_INVALID_MODE'
}

d = something
mode = modes[d]
```