# What is the syntactical equivalent to switch/case in Python?

Tags: python, syntax, switch-statement, conditional-statements, pattern-matching

Programming languages like C/C++, C#, Java, JavaScript and Pascal <sup>([Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#mw-content-text:%7E:text=used%20in%20programming%20languages%20like%20C%2FC%2B%2B%2C,C%2FC%2B%2B%2C%20C%23%2C%20Visual%20Basic%20.NET%2C%20Java))</sup> have a combination of `switch` and `case` statements (sometimes also called `select` or `inspect`) which allow you to check one value against several conditions to perform certain actions.

```
my_value = 10;
switch(my_value) {
    case 10:
        print("The number is ten");
    case 2*10:
        print("The number is the double of ten");
    case 100:
        print("The number is one hundred");
    default:
        print("The number is none of 10, 2*10 or 100");
}
```

<sup>Pseudo-Code to depict the special syntax of the `switch`-`case` construct.</sup>

Being aware of functional equivalents like [dictionary-lookups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11479840/6685358), is there a purely **syntactical** equivalent to the above programming construct?

Comment: Note: I consider this question **not a duplicate**, because I'm explicitly asking for a **syntax-only** way of accomplishing this control flow structure. As all the other popular questions don't allow any more answers, and as many people just look up the first answer - not reading through all the comments - they might not find this new official solution. This self-answered post is therefore intended to be the new standard "one-stop-shop" answer to the general question, with almost every aspect covered in it, so that everyone from a beginner to an experienced developer will find what they need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Comment: the inability to add a new answer to a question does not mean a new question is warranted. Community posts were made to be edited which is in my opinion preferable to creating new questions that are essentially duplicates. If we create a new question and answer for each feature change in a language SO would become a mess because for each version of a language you will have to search for different questions rather than having one continually updated source. I appreciate your answer so thank you for taking the time to write it but I would prefer if you had edited the top community answer

Comment: Thank you for the honest opinion, Kevin. Unfortunately, my top edit was rejected I think. For the future though, your approach seems like the way to go - thanks.

Comment: [Python 3.10 (2021) has it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python/60211#60211).

Answer (score 97, accepted):

## TL;DR

As of **Python 3.10.0** *(alpha6 [released](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html) March 30, 2021)*, Python has an official syntactical equivalent called [**`match`**](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#syntax-and-operations:%7E:text=A%20match%20statement%20takes%20an%20expression,as%20one%20or%20more%20case%20blocks.).

The basic syntax is:

```py
match value:
    case condition:
        action(s)
    ...
```

---

For older Python versions, there are only workarounds if you don't want to resort to `if`-`elif`-`else`.
See this excellent [community post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python) for a collection of some.

## Example

```py
my_value = 10
match my_value:
    case 10:
        print("The number is ten")
    case 2*10:
        print("The number is the double of ten")
    case 100:
        print("The number is one hundred")
    case _:
        # this is the default handler if none
        # of the above cases match.
        print("The number is none of 10, 2*10 or 100")
```

Therefore, other answers involving workarounds aren't valid anymore - also from a performance point of view.

## Important Notices

If coming from languages which support `switch` and `case`, it's likely that you already know about their behavior. With Python, there are some differences to note though.

- **Cases don't fall through**

  It's common that languages with `switch`-`case` statements execute **every** case the value matches - from top to bottom. Hence, there is a third statement - `break` - to be used in `switch`-`case` constructs if you don't want to fall through:

  ```
  value = 10
  switch (value) {
      case 10:
          print("Value is ten");
      case 2*5:
          print("Value is the double of five");
          break;
      case 20/2:
          print("Value is the half of twenty");
      default:
          print("This is just the default action.");
  }
  ```

  In this example, the first **two** cases would be executed because the first case falls through. If there was no `break` statement inside the second case, all cases, including the default one, would be executed.

  **In Python, *only the first matching case* is being executed. You can think of it like every case would contain a hidden `break` statement.**
- **Variable references don't work as a condition**

  ```py
  base_color = "red"
  chosen_color = "green"
  match chosen_color:
      case base_color:
          print("Yes, it matches!")
  ```

  This code does actually print that the colors match!

  **Bare variable references as case conditions will always match.**

  Regardless, literals like `case "red": ...` and *qualified* (i.e. dotted) names like `case AllColors.red` work like expected - no need to be scared of them.

  All of this is the case, because the Python Software Foundation did not decide to just copy another boring control flow model, but to actually implement a fully-fledged *pattern matcher* which is more than just a `switch`-`case` statement. More on this can be found in the next section.

## Powerful Pattern Matching

`match` - **M**atch **a**in'**t** **c**ase **h**ooey

<sup>Specification and information provided in the [Python Enhancement Proposals (PEP) nos. 634-636](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/)</sup>

In Python, `match` is actually much more than a simple switch - therefore probably the name. It features special functionality like deep placeholders and wildcards.

*Examples inspired by reading the documentation - so you don't have to:*

```py
match point:
    case (0, 0):
        print("Origin")
    case (0, y):
        print("Our current Y position is", y, " now.")
```

You can match arbitrary nested data structures, including placeholders. In the above example, we are matching a tuple with two items where in the second case, we use a placeholder `y` that gets its value assigned upon matching.

You can also match class attributes, in a very similar fashion:

```py
class Point:
    x: int
    y: int

def location(point):
    match point:
        case Point(x=0, y=0):
            print("Origin is the point's location.")
        case Point(x=0, y=y):
            print("The point lies on the y axis at a height of", y, "units.")
```

**This also explains why you can't match single variable references in case conditions:** you don't actually match against the value of that variable but actually introduce a placeholder of that same name!
Therefore, if you were going to print `chosen_color` like this:

```py
base_color = "red"
chosen_color = "green"
match chosen_color:
    case base_color:
        print("Our base color is", base_color)
```

It would actually print out

> Our base color is green

because the `base_color` is now a placeholder which gets assigned the value of our `chosen_color`.

There are a lot more use cases for this advanced pattern matching, an interesting couple of them mentioned in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching).

## Epilogue

It will take its time until Python 3.10 gets its deserved adoption. Python 3.10.0 is set to be released stable on **October 4, 2021** - meaning it might be included in Ubuntu 22.04 and up.

If you just want to play around and write programs for yourself, deploy them to your own server, or if you intend to distribute your creations in packaged form and not as plain source code files, give this new feature already a try in your programs - it's going to be a benefit!

## Addendum

#### Trying Python 3.10.0

For Windows and macOS users, [this page](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3100a6/#content:%7E:text=Files) features the official installer downloads.

On [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) and Ubuntu, you can use the very popular "DeadSnakes"-project PPA:

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.10
python3.10 --version
```

#### Trying Python 3.10.0 without destroying your system

[Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)) is an option for using Python 3.10 without any complicated setup steps and in a completely isolated environment.

`docker run -it python:3.10.0a6-alpine`

And that's it. As the time passes by, new alpha or beta versions might be released. You will want to replace the `a6` with a [different version](https://hub.docker.com/_/python?tab=description&page=1&ordering=last_updated#contextNav:%7E:text=Simple%20Tags) then.

Comment: I was about to comment that this seems like an impeccably timed question (given it hasn't been a day since the alpha was released) before I noticed you answered it yourself! Great answer, and thanks for adding it to the SO python knowledgebase. :)

Comment: Yes, coincidentally coming across the alpha announcement and being so excited about this new powerful feature, I thought it'd be worth introducing it to the SO Python community - thanks for your comment. :)

Comment: The design of match/case is appalling. Users who have long been hoping for a switch/case equivalent are rebuffed again. What annoys me most is that we can't match against variables (non-dotted constants), and the high indentation - the colon after `match` and the second tab could simply have been omitted (IIRC the PEP doesn't even discuss this as rejected idea).
Structure matching is certainly interesting, but I wonder if there's not a cleaner way to integrate this, e.g. with some kind of shape objects.
One thing is clear to me: The PEPs should never, ever have been accepted in that form.

Answer (score 12):

#### Pre-Python 3.10.0 answer

There is not. It is usually done in two ways, depending on the code context:

#### 1. if/elif:

Using the if/elif syntax you can have the most similar version of switch case:

```
my_value = 10;
if my_value == 10:
    print("The number is ten")
elif my_value == 2*10:
    print("The number is the double of ten")
elif my_value == 100:
    print("The number is one hundred")
else:
    print("The number is none of 10, 2*10 or 100")
```

#### 2. Dict lookup:

Another less common way, is to make a dict and assign at each condition of the switch/case a corresponding function to be called:

```
my_value = 10;

def def_action():
    print("The number is none of 10, 2*10 or 100")

def ten_action():
    print("The number is ten")

def double_ten_action():
    print("The number is ten")

def hundred_action():
    print("The number is one hundred")

{
    10: ten_action,
    2*10: double_ten_action,
    100: hundred_action,
}.get(
    my_value,
    def_action # This is the final else, if no match if found
)()
```

This, despite being less [Pythonic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pythonic#Adjective), is useful when inside the various cases you have a lot of code that worsen readability.