# optimize(shorten) multiple if statements

Tags: python

I wrote this code by lots searching and thinking! but certainly it is ill-optimized.

```
class Searching_section(BaseModel):
    Hostname: Union[str, None] = None
    IP: Union[str, None] = None
    MAC: Union[str, None] = None


def search_select(search_option: Searching_section):
    if Hostname_Validation(search_option.Hostname):
        blocks, others = extract_blocks(app.conf_file_path)
        filter_object = filter(lambda a: search_option.Hostname in a, blocks)
        print(list(filter_object)) 
    elif MAC_Validation(search_option.MAC):
        blocks, others = extract_blocks(app.conf_file_path)
        filter_object = filter(lambda a: search_option.MAC in a, blocks)
        print(list(filter_object)) 
    elif IP_Validation(search_option.IP):
        blocks, others = extract_blocks(app.conf_file_path)
        filter_object = filter(lambda a: search_option.IP in a, blocks)
        print(list(filter_object))
```

the main question is how can it be written so instead of 3 if statements it could be written in just one?

I couldn't think of anyway

Comment: `if check1 or check2 or check3`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Would you care to elaborate? thanks

Comment: Why is it ill-optimized?

Comment: @pho because I seem to have repeated myself a lot! DRY was it, right? :)

Comment: There is some [good information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66877130/what-is-the-syntactical-equivalent-to-switch-case-in-python) regarding a Python equivalent of a "switch" statement. 

These techniques can make your code more readable. 

An argument for the speed is encourged

Comment: Each `if` statement calls a different function with a different attribute of `search_option`, and does different things. You could certainly define `filter_function = lambda a: search_option.Hostname in a` and so on inside each `if` block, and move the actual filtering and printing (`filter_object = filter(filter_function, blocks); print(list(filter_object))`) outside the `if..elif` block, but that isn't any more "optimized" than what you have. DRY isn't a blanket statement. Repetition, when required, is required :)

Comment: @pho Thank you for your being so kind to answer. appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
def search_select(search_option: Searching_section):
    for validation, search in [
            (Hostname_Validation, search_option.Hostname),
            (MAC_Validation, search_option.MAC),
            (IP_Validation, search_option.IP)
        ]:
        if validation(search):
            blocks, others = extract_blocks(app.conf_file_path)
            filter_object = filter(lambda a: search in a, blocks)
            print(list(filter_object))
            return
```

First identify the changing parts of the three if/elif blocks which are the validation function and the `search_option` component (appears in condition and the `lambda`).

Replace them by variables and create a little table with the values to insert. Here I used a list of tuples `(<validation function>, <search component>)`. Then you can iterate over the list with a for-loop.

If the condition is true for one list entry, the code is executed and then the function is left with `return`. If there would be something to do in the function after the loop, `break` could be used instead.

Comment: I agree! A very genius solution. Some context would be nice though.

Comment: @Jamie_D I added some explanation to the answer.